# Setting Permissions in Android Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I am currently using sessions to log user into Facebook.

```
private Session createSession() {
        Session activeSession = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (activeSession == null || activeSession.getState().isClosed()) {
            activeSession = new Session.Builder(this).setApplicationId(APP_ID).build();
            Session.setActiveSession(activeSession);
        }
        return activeSession;
    }
```

It is so far simple and straight forward. Is there a way to modify permissions in a similar way, or do i absolutely need to use the Login Button.

to be specific-
I wish to get user notification. So I need extended permission  `manage_notifications`.